# Table not referenced in recursive PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

for some reasons I don't have, a table, although referenced in the query, is not referenced according to the error.

The query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE temptable AS (
    SELECT part_id, tracability_component1, tracability_component2, tracability_component3, tracking_id
    FROM kpitr.subop_result SR
    LEFT JOIN kpitr.part_produce PP ON PP.supplier_id || PP.product_id LIKE SR.tracability_component1 OR PP.supplier_id || PP.product_id LIKE SR.tracability_component2 OR PP.supplier_id || PP.product_id LIKE SR.tracability_component3
    WHERE part_id LIKE '%0005001723A031T'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SR2.part_id, SR2.tracability_component1, SR2.tracability_component2, SR2.tracability_component3, PP2.tracking_id
    FROM kpitr.subop_result SR2, temptable
    LEFT JOIN kpitr.part_produce PP2 ON PP2.supplier_id || PP2.product_id LIKE SR2.tracability_component1 OR PP2.supplier_id || PP2.product_id LIKE SR2.tracability_component2 OR PP2.supplier_id || PP2.product_id LIKE SR2.tracability_component3 OR SR2.part_id LIKE temptable.tracking_id
)
SELECT * FROM temptable
```

The error :

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "sr2"
LINE 9: ...uce PP2 ON PP2.supplier_id || PP2.product_id LIKE SR2.tracab...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "sr2", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 678
```

I believe I place in the wrong order something, or I missed sometinh, but after some tests, it didn't change anything.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Explicit `JOIN`'s are evaluated before implicit, comma separated joins. This means your `ON` clause has no access to kpitr.subop_result columns.

Comment: You mean that it would be better to do a 
SELECT ...
 FROM kpitr.subop_result SR2, kpitr.part_produce PP2, temptable
WHERE <conditions of preisous JOIN> ?

Comment: The opposite, switch to explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere.

Comment: I'm quite lost. What do you mean by "everywhere" ? For me, LEFT JOIN are explicit no ? So the only place I see is the "WHERE part_id LIKE ...".

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, after some tries :

```
WITH RECURSIVE temptable AS (
    SELECT SR1.part_id, SR1.tracability_component1, SR1.tracability_component2, SR1.tracability_component3, PP1.tracking_id
    FROM kpitr.subop_result SR1
    LEFT JOIN kpitr.part_produce PP1 ON UPPER(PP1.reference) || UPPER(PP1.product_id) = UPPER(SR1.tracability_component1) OR UPPER(PP1.reference) || UPPER(PP1.product_id) = UPPER(SR1.tracability_component2) OR UPPER(PP1.reference) || UPPER(PP1.product_id) = UPPER(SR1.tracability_component3)
    WHERE part_id LIKE '%0005001723A031T' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sr.part_id, sr.tracability_component1, sr.tracability_component2, sr.tracability_component3, pp.tracking_id
    FROM kpitr.subop_result sr
    JOIN temptable ON UPPER(sr.part_id) = UPPER(temptable.tracability_component1) OR UPPER(sr.part_id) = UPPER(temptable.tracability_component2) OR UPPER(sr.part_id) = UPPER(temptable.tracability_component3) OR UPPER(sr.part_id) = UPPER(temptable.tracking_id)
    LEFT JOIN kpitr.part_produce pp ON UPPER(pp.reference) || UPPER(pp.product_id) = UPPER(sr.tracability_component1) OR UPPER(pp.reference) || UPPER(pp.product_id) = UPPER(sr.tracability_component2) OR UPPER(pp.reference) || UPPER(pp.product_id) = UPPER(sr.tracability_component3)
)
SELECT * FROM temptable
```

Comment: Please include a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/33754116)